# Google Sheet Function - Logical

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to filter and count the number of people for our food count but am having a bit trouble in sorting it out.

I want to create a function where if a specific day and the location is met then the box will count
e.g If today is John's day off (monday) and he is onsite then we should not count or add him to free meals. We only add if John is not on day off and he is "onsite" and not in the hotel.

[image]

Here's a snippet.

I'm thinking of a function - IF the 3 rows ( K : M ) is not equal to Today() and location for breakfast is not equal to "Hotel" > count + 
Please help..

Comment: Welcome. Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: Where is the data about the "day off"? Also, could you show what you tried till now? Any formula you are working on?

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired output